# Router and IP address

Tags: networking, network-protocols

A Networking MCQ question came in Gate 2008 not a homework.
Host X has IP address `192.168.1.97` and is connected through two Routers R1 and R2 to another host Y with IP address `192.168.1.80`. Router R1 has IP address `192.168.1.135` and `192.168.1.110`. R2 has IP addresses `192.168.1.67`and `192.168.1.155` The netmask used in network is `255.255.255.224`.
**How many distinct subnets are guarenteed to already exist in network? Options (a)1 (b)2 (c)3 (d)6 and Which IP address should X configure its gateway as? options should be one of the router addresses given for R1 and R2**

Comment: Sounds like a school assignment :P

Comment: Yes, all his questions are from some preparation or course. No idea if he thinks he learns anything when always asking others for the solution...

Comment: No it came in gate 2008. Its a ALL INDIA ENTRANCE EXAMINATION.came way back in 2008 . I cant solve it ,because i dont know how to

Comment: @QueueTank, check my answer, if you want more information just ask.

Comment: I checked ,i commented on it the options given in the mcq.You are juz telling the no. of subnets dats obviously 2^n number of 1 ,bt dis is not wat question is asking for

Comment: @QueueTank, this is absolute basics ... I suggest you look into subnetting a little deeper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your setup is using `3 subnets (Host X - R1, R1 - R2, R2 - Host Y)`. You should have 8 subnets in total and 30 available hosts per subnet.

Host X should normally configure the connected router interface as his `default gateway, so 192.168.1.110`.

Checkout both links for more info on subnetting:

- http://www.cisco.com/en/US/tech/tk365/technologies_tech_note09186a00800a67f5.shtml
- http://www.fruned.com/dwn/Network-Fundamentals-CCNA-Exploration-Companion-Guide-Mark%20A.%20Dye.pdf (Chapter 6)

Comment: options for question (1) are 1,2,3,6 and for 2nd its got to be one of the router addresses

Comment: @QueueTank, there you go. I thought you meant total, but you mean amount of subnets used, correct?

Comment: I edited the question and have added the options,This is asking for number of distinct subnets that are guarenteed to already exist.This is all wat d question says

Comment: @QueueTank, like my answer states `there are 3 subnets in use (of the 8 you have)` and the default gateway for Host X is `192.168.1.110` interface of R1 in the subnet of Host X ...

Comment: okk Going through the link .. thanks

Comment: and for Y the subnet is 192.168.1.67 right?? and what is the subnet for R1-R2 i mean by logical and gives me 192.168.1.64

Comment: Subnet for host Y and R2 interface is `.64 - .95`, subnet for host X and R1 interface is `.96 - .127`, subnet for R1 and R2 is `.128 - .159`

Comment: Thanks for your help and the link ,totally clear :)